# How to put figure caption in center?

Tags: diagrams

I am working on a figure:

[image]

I added a caption to it, but the title is not under the diagram.

[image]

Full code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{tikz-cd}    
\newcommand{\stirlingi}[2]{\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}    
\newcommand{\stirlingii}[2]{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}       
\newcommand{\tstirlingi}[2]{\genfrac[]{0pt}{1}{#1}{#2}}       
\newcommand{\tstirlingii}[2]{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{1}{#1}{#2}}       
\usepackage{tikz-cd}       
\usepackage{capt-of}       
\begin{document}       
    \begin{figure}    
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=8em,column sep=4em]     
        & x^n \arrow[dl,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']    
        \arrow[dr,"\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']    
        \\    
        x^{(n)} \arrow[ur,"\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']    
        \arrow[rr,"{L(n,k)}"]    
        &&    
        (x)_{n} \arrow[ul,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']    
        \arrow[ll,bend left=15,"{(-1)^{n-k}L(n,k)}"]    
    \end{tikzcd}    
    \begin{center}    
        \caption{figure caption}    
    \end{center}    
    \end{figure}     
\end{document}
```

How do I put caption under the diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to recommending that you use a `\centering` directive on the contents of the `figure` environment in order to achieve your primary formatting objective, I would also like to suggest that you define the `\tstirlingi` and `\tstirlingii` macros not via `\genfrac` directives but in terms of the `bsmallmatrix` and `Bsmallmatrix` environments that are provided by the `mathtools` package (which, in turn, is a superset of the `amsmath` package). By using the machinery of the `bsmallmatrix` and `Bsmallmatrix` environments, you'll get ever so slightly more "squat" looking expressions, which -- I would argue -- are ever so slightly more readable/legible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '[bB]smallmatrix' environments
\newcommand{\tstirlingi} [2]{\begin{bsmallmatrix} #1\\#2 \end{bsmallmatrix}}       
\newcommand{\tstirlingii}[2]{\begin{Bsmallmatrix} #1\\#2 \end{Bsmallmatrix}}       
\usepackage{tikz-cd}          
     
\begin{document}       
\begin{figure}[ht]  
\centering  % <-- new
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=8em,column sep=4em]     
        & \mskip5mu x^n  
        \arrow[dl,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']    
        \arrow[dr,"\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']    
        \\    
        x^{(n)} 
        \arrow[ur,"\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']    
        \arrow[rr,"{L(n,k)}"]    
        &&    
        (x)_{n}
        \arrow[ul,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']    
        \arrow[ll,bend left=15,"{(-1)^{n-k}L(n,k)}"]    
    \end{tikzcd}    
    
\caption{Figure caption}    
   
\end{figure}     
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With your class and packages, the caption is automatically centred. What is not centred is your commutative diagram. To centre this, you would have to place it inside your `centre` environment.

However, it would be better to use `\centering` in your figure instead of the `center` environment to avoid the extra vertical space this adds.

You should also specify floating parameters like `[htpb]` for your figure to give latex the best possible options to place the figure for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\stirlingi}[2]{\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\stirlingii}[2]{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tstirlingi}[2]{\genfrac[]{0pt}{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tstirlingii}[2]{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{1}{#1}{#2}}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzcd}
[row sep=8em,column sep=4em]
& x^n \arrow[dl,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']
\arrow[dr,"\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']
\\
x^{(n)} \arrow[ur,"\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']
\arrow[rr,"{L(n,k)}"]
&&
(x)_{n} \arrow[ul,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']
\arrow[ll,bend left=15,"{(-1)^{n-k}L(n,k)}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\caption{figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]